# Error while setting the value of a global private class property in javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a code in which I declare a private class member using "#" and then initialize it in the constructor and then when I try to set / access the value I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read private member #mouse from an object whose class did not declare it
    at mouseDownEvent
```

where the **mouseDownEvent** is the function, where I try to access the values

code example: ( refer to the **EDIT** code )

```
class Testing
{
   #property;
   constructor()
   {
      this.#property = new Vector2();
   }

   mouseDownEvent()
   {
      this.#mouse.x = somevalue; <- error is here
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
class Testing
{
   #mouse;
   constructor()
   {
      this.#mouse= new Vector2();
   }

   mouseDownEvent()
   {
      this.#mouse.x = somevalue; <- error is here
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the above code snippet correct? You have declared and initialized `#property`, but setting `#mouse` in the function.

Comment: @UdithGunaratna yes, this is the official raycaster code: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster

after initializing in the constructor, the mouse.x and mouse.y both have value 0, and it works if i try to set the value in the contructor

but as soon as i try to do it from outside of the constructor ( from a function of the same class ) it gives me an error

also, it should be valid, shouldn't it be cause it's a global property?

Comment: No, what I meant was, in your above code, you haven't declared the `#mouse` property. (like you have declared the `#property`)

Comment: my bad, it's #mouse in my original code

i just messed up while typing it here, i'll edit it out as a new section. Gimme a minute

It also produces the same error, if i initialize the #mouse, in the global scope, outside of the constructor

Comment: From where do you call the `mouseDownEvent()`?

Comment: @UdithGunaratna i have attached the mousedownEvent() to mousedown event click

so i call the "mouseDownEvent()" using ->>

window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownEvent(), false)

Comment: Then you may need to bind `mouseDownEvent()` to this instance, like `window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownEvent.bind(this)(), false)`

Comment: @UdithGunaratna Hey thanks for your help, i did as you said and it works now. Do you wanna put the last comment of yours as reply, so i can mark it as answer. Also i would really appreciate if you could point me towards some materail that i can read in order to understand why this was happening

Please and Thank You!

Comment: I added the above as a separate answer and also added a reference to read further about JS bind(). Please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are passing the `mouseDownEvent` function to an event listener, the value of `this` will not be this Testing instance when it is actually invoked. So you need to **bind** it to this instance when passing it to the event handler as below.

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownEvent.bind(this)(), false)
```

You can read further about Javascript bind() from below link.
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-bind/